# Spotify api invalid_grant, Invalid authorization code in only Firefox

Tags: firefox, spotify-app

I'm able to authenticate on Chrome, Safari etc. except Firefox.
the authentication flow url is

> [https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?client_id={clientId}&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/api/callback&scope=playlist-modify-private%20playlist-read-private%20user-read-private&state=](https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?client_id=%7BclientId%7D&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/api/callback&scope=playlist-modify-private%20playlist-read-private%20user-read-private&state=)

I get error of

```
    error: 'invalid_grant',
    error_description: 'Invalid authorization code'
  },
  headers: {
    date: 'Tue, 27 Jul 2021 12:41:04 GMT',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'set-cookie': [
      '__Host-device_id=AQCdPASWLqstG_ETwdZUSE3OjrrjhV2-9IOc0sxdvUy_bkMgdPA5iU0rDpwPcy4c7gt-rJf1ujGqNK6eXsm1kHDSKdgXabGa2bc;Version=1;Path=/;Max-Age=2147483647;Secure;HttpOnly;SameSite=Lax',
      'sp_tr=false;Version=1;Domain=accounts.spotify.com;Path=/;Secure;SameSite=Lax'
    ],
    'sp-trace-id': '3663508cfc2723f5',
    'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=31536000',
    'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
    'content-encoding': 'gzip',
    vary: 'Accept-Encoding',
    server: 'envoy',
    via: 'HTTP/2 edgeproxy, 1.1 google',
    'alt-svc': 'clear',
    connection: 'close',
    'transfer-encoding': 'chunked'
  },
  statusCode: 400
}
```